# how to calculate of a program having unkown iterations

Tags: java, time-complexity

I have a program of which I am unable to find out the time complexity.
Pseudo-code of the mentioned program is as follows:

```
n = 10
while n > 1
  print n;
  if n is even
   n = n / 2
  else
   n = 11 * n + 1
endwhile
```

Can anyone suggest me how to find out time complexity of this program and any of similar kind of programs like this one, where measuring of iterations are unpredictable.

Comment: It's definitely predictable. You can just write out how `n` changes. Or derive a mathematical formula. With that said, I'm not even sure this terminates. It probably does but only when `n` becomes be a power of two, so it only ever goes in the `if` and not the `else`.

Comment: Number of counts in the mentioned program are 61...how to derive a mathematical formula in this case or what might be the time complexity of the said program.

Comment: Is the `if..else` clause in the while loop? If yes, please indent it.

Comment: @AkshayaAmar this is the correct question to ask. Because your program will *always* go through 61 iterations. As I said, it's not unpredictable.

Comment: complexity is O(n), because any number of linear iteration complexity will be O(n)

Comment: @MdMahamudulHasan what do you mean? Its not linear. It's most definitely not iterating 1..(n-1), either.

Comment: @VLAZ just mistakenly written, i changed my comment see that please

Comment: @PalLaden done indenting

Comment: It's not known if the collatz sequence always terminates, and that's a similar program to this one (with a different constant -- whereas you have 11, it has 3). So there's no known way of computing the time complexity of programs like this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is in general no known way to know even if sequences like this even terminate (cf: collatz sequence).

Comment: May I suggest that if you really want a java answer, that you use java code rather than pseudocode.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a variation on the Collatz conjecture. The number of iterations you have to perform is equal to the total stopping time. It is also stated on the wiki page that it is not known whether every number eventually reaches 1.

Your case is slightly different in that it uses a different factor. It uses 11 instead of 3. We could try all sorts of different factors. If you use 5 instead of 11 (or 3) and start with `n=5` you get a sequence which repeats it self.

```
  5 ->  5 * 5 + 1 = 26
 26 ->     26 / 2 = 13
 13 -> 5 * 13 + 1 = 66
 66 ->     66 / 2 = 33
 33 -> 5 * 33 + 1 = 166
166 ->    166 / 2 = 83
 83 -> 5 * 83 + 1 = 416
416 ->    416 / 2 = 208
208 ->    208 / 2 = 104
104 ->    104 / 2 = 52
 52 ->     52 / 2 = 26
 26 ->     26 / 2 = 13 (back to line 2)
```

When trying the same with factor 11 on a couple of odd numbers it seems to create divergent sequences. Meaning it will not stop (unless it overflows your integer type) and keeps growing without going into a loop. What would be left to do is to show that this happens (some mathematical proof perhaps), which may or may not be an easy task.

In general you need to show that there is some bound on the number of iterations that can occur, using specific details of the algorithm in question. For instance if the question used 5 instead of 11 the answer would be that your program will loop forever on some inputs. Any `2 ** k * 5` would cause infinite looping, so in Big O notation there exists no function which can be a valid bound for the time complexity.

Collatz Conjecture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Comment: thank you for sharing this valuable information...It's quite helpful !!!

Answer (score 1):

you are right though that different values of n will yield different iterations. (online compiler here https://rextester.com/PKCTO53046)

```
start value 32: iteration 5
start value 31: iteration 31
start value 30: iteration 49
start value 29: iteration 67
start value 28: iteration 58
start value 27: iteration 81
start value 26: iteration 98
start value 25: iteration 89
start value 24: iteration 76
start value 23: iteration 35
start value 22: iteration 80
start value 21: iteration 71
start value 20: iteration 62
start value 19: iteration 49
start value 18: iteration 93
start value 17: iteration 71
start value 16: iteration 4
start value 15: iteration 48
start value 14: iteration 57
start value 13: iteration 97
start value 12: iteration 75
start value 11: iteration 79
start value 10: iteration 61
start value 9: iteration 92
start value 8: iteration 3
start value 7: iteration 56
start value 6: iteration 74 
start value 5: iteration 60
start value 4: iteration 2
start value 3: iteration 73
start value 2: iteration 1
start value 1: iteration 0
```

so in your case you want to calculate how many iterations it takes for your int to overflow into negative based on your starting value, and the multiplier.

you need to rewrite your algo into a series of for loops based on the pattern of n- to the number of iteration (rather than the original "n" number), to be your N value.

you need to break your algorithm into different operations. you can see there's actually a pattern.

for example each operation can be calculated like below:

- those n*2 (2,4,8,16,etc) is solved in n^0.5  (1,2,3,4,...)
- those n*3
  (3,6,12,24,etc) is solved in 72+(n/3) (73,74,75,...)
- those n*5 (5,10,20,etc) is solved in (61,62,63,...)
- those n*7 (7,14,28,etc) is solved in (56,57,58,...)

etc...

you add those up and take the highest O for the algorithm. my guess is that value will be O(N) after you remove all the constants.

based on https://medium.com/dataseries/how-to-calculate-time-complexity-with-big-o-notation-9afe33aa4c46

```
1 Break your algorithm/function into individual operations
2 Calculate the Big O of each operation
3 Add up the Big O of each operation together
4 Remove the constants
5 Find the highest order term — this will be what we consider the Big O of our algorithm/function
```

Comment: @thank u so much for the clarification and will take your suggestions into consideration.